# How to get system vibration data android?

Tags: android, android-vibration

Is it possible to get system vibration pattern as a `long[]` array? For example standard SMS vibration pattern or current selected in preferences SMS vibration signal.

Comment: Do you want to get the system default pattern?

Comment: yep, if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to get the default patterns of your current device as a `long[]` array. You'll probably have to do a trial and error approach on this. And set a bunch of if's on your code to choose a different vibration pattern depending on the device or cellphone brand.

Something like:

**YourActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Vibrator;

private long[] patt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String man = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER; 

    if (man.equals("SAMSUNG")) {
        patt = {0l,300l,50l,350l};
    }
    else {
        patt = {0l,200l,100l,100l};
    }

    vibrate(patt);
}

private void vibrate(long[] pattern) {
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        if (v.hasVibrator()) {
           v.vibrate(pattern,-1);
        }            
    }
```

And don't forget to add the permission to vibrate.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/os/Build.html) for `android.os.Build` information.